# window in javascript . thats ok. but what kind of "window" is used for my code?

Tags: javascript, oncreate

what does window means in java-script code ? it becomes many times for many reason. but why it appeared in this inheritance code ?

```
(function() {
    var Orb = function() {
    this.initialize();
    }
    Orb.prototype = new createjs.Shape();
    Orb.prototype.Shape_initialize = Orb.prototype.initialize;
    Orb.prototype.initialize = function() {
    this.Shape_initialize();
    }
    window.Orb = Orb;
    }());
```

now window.orb in this code . why window is used ? and what is its javascript or easeljs name and importance .

Answer (score 0):

It JavaScript it is just a variable name.

For JS running in a webpage, in a browser, it points to [the global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

The code is just creating a global variable called `Orb`.